# Rename the excel sheet being generated in rally

Tags: excel, csv, extjs, rally, export-to-csv

I created a custom report which shows the total number of days each story stayed in each kanban state.I am able to export the data from report to CSV. But the name of excel sheet downloaded is "download.xls" by default. How to rename the excel sheet generated. Also when I open the excel file, It gives a warning saying "The file format and extension of "download.xls" dont match.The file could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, dont open it. Do you want to open it anyway?". But when i click "yes", the file opens normally displaying the data. I want to get rid of this warning. Is there any way I can code so that this warning does not occur. Kindly advise.
code:
code to create button:

```
var button =Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
        text     : 'Export',
        renderTo : Ext.getBody(),
            handler: function() {
                that.onClickExport();
            }
        }
```

});

code to create grid:

```
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            store: mydata,
            id: 'taskgrid',
            columns: [
            {
                text: 'ID', 
                dataIndex: 'FormattedID',
                locked:true,
            },
            {
                text: 'Story Name', 
                dataIndex: 'Name',
                locked:true,
            },
            {
             text: 'Defined',
             dataIndex: 'def',
             lockable: false,
             },
             {
             text: 'In Dev', 
             dataIndex: 'dev',
             lockable: false,
             },
             {
             text: 'Completed',
             dataIndex: 'comp',
             lockable: false,
             }
        ],
        height: 300,
        width: 400,
         viewConfig: {
            stripeRows: true
        } 

    });
    this.add(button);
    this.add(grid);
```

export to CSV function:

```
onClickExport: function () {

if (/*@cc_on!@*/0) { //Exporting to Excel not supported in IE
    Ext.Msg.alert('Error', 'Exporting to CSV is not supported in Internet Explorer. Please switch to a different browser and try again.');
} else if (document.getElementById('taskgrid')) {

    Ext.getBody().mask('Exporting the Report...');

    setTimeout(function () {
        var template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-' +
            'microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head>' +
            '<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>' +
            '{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet>' +
            '</x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}' +
            '</table></body></html>';

        var base64 = function (s) {
            return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)));
        };
        var format = function (s, c) {
            return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) {
                return c[p];
            })
        };
        var table = document.getElementById('taskgrid');
        console.log("table :", table);
        var excel_data = '<tr>';
        Ext.Array.each(table.innerHTML.match(/<span .*?x-column-header-text.*?>.*?<\/span>/gm), function (column_header_span) {
            excel_data += (column_header_span.replace(/span/g, 'td'));
        });
        excel_data += '</tr>';
        console.log("excel data: ",excel_data);
        Ext.Array.each(table.innerHTML.match(/<tr class="x-grid-row.*?<\/tr>/gm), function (line) {
        alert(line);
            excel_data += line.replace(/[^\011\012\015\040-\177]/g, '>>');
        alert(line);
        });
        var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: excel_data};
        window.location.href = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,' + base64(format(template, ctx));
        Ext.getBody().unmask();
    }, 500);
}else{
console.log("taskgrid does not exist");
}
```

}
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For renaming the excel you should use the following code instead of         `window.location.href = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,' + base64(format(template, ctx));`

use following code:

```
var el = Ext.DomHelper.append(document.body, {
             tag: "a",
             download: '<yourFileName>.xls',
             href: 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,' + base64(format(template, ctx))
});
 el.click();     
 Ext.fly(el).destroy();
```

Comment: Thanks. But is there anyway to get rid of the warning mentioned in the question? @ankit chaudhary

Comment: I also need the solution for this